# why 'axis' is an invalid keyword argument for print()?

Tags: python-3.x

Why is `axis an invalid keyword argument for`print()` ?

```
print(np.sum([[0,1],[0,5]]), axis=0)
print(np.sum([[0,1],[0,5]]), axis=1)
```

I have tried the above code but it is giving the error `'axis' is an invalid keyword argument for print()`

Comment: Voting to close as typo. You could refer to the documentation for print method. But your parenthesis are off

Answer (score 4):

Because it is.
print() is just a general python function, and it has nothing to do with numpy nor axis.
The correct code is this

```
print(np.sum([[0,1],[0,5]], axis=0))
print(np.sum([[0,1],[0,5]], axis=1))
```

with `axis` as keyword argument for `np.sum()`.